# Android :: Bind Service for all activity

Tags: java, android

I want to do somethings like topic said but I have no idea what should be the step.

I can bind service for each activity and call service methods or service call activity methods.

This is some workaround. I use IBinder approach to communicate between service and activity.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Toast.makeText(Screen1.this, "Service is connected", 1000).show();
            mBounded = true;
            MqttPushService.LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (MqttPushService.LocalBinder)service;
            mService = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
            mService.setServiceCallbacks(Screen1.this);
            //get temp info
            try {
                mService.send("info","topic1/sensor1");
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Toast.makeText(Screen1.this, "Service is disconnected", 1000).show();
            mBounded = false;
            mService = null;
        }
    };


    //Bind Service and Activity
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,MqttPushService.class);
    bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

}//END of onStart()

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(mBounded) {
        mService.setServiceCallbacks(null); // unregister
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBounded = false;
    }
}//END of onStop()
```

However, I can't bind service to all activities in one time.

I think of using Base Activity Class but no hope.

I try to implement binding service in base class and let other extend this base service

**BASECLASS**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mBounded = true;
            MqttPushService.LocalBinder mLocalBinder = (MqttPushService.LocalBinder)service;
            mService = mLocalBinder.getServerInstance();
            mService.setServiceCallbacks(BaseActivity.this);

            mListener.doServiceConnected();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service is connected", 0).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBounded = false;
            mService = null;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service is disconnected", 0).show();
        }
    };

    //Bind MQTT Service and Activity
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,MqttPushService.class);
    bindService(mIntent, mConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(mBounded) {
        mService.setServiceCallbacks(null); // unregister
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBounded = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void doSomething(String act) {
    mListener.doServiceReturn(act);
}

protected void setServiceAttachedListener(onServiceAttached listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public interface onServiceAttached{
    void doServiceConnected();
    void doServiceReturn(String act);
}
```

When Screen1.class (First Activity) set callbacks methods

1. call service method and do some task
2. listen for returning resul and do some task

There is no problem in this class but when I intent and new screen(SleepMode.class)
which is implementation like this class but service Log.d me that null of serviceCallBacks.
when service want to call activity methods.

```
public class Screen1 extends BaseActivity implements BaseActivity.onServiceAttached  {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null, false);
    mDrawer.addView(contentView, 0);

    setServiceAttachedListener(Screen1.this);
}

@Override
public void doServiceConnected() {

    try {
        mService.send("info","topic1/sensor1");
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void doServiceReturn(String act) {
    if (act.equals("SCREEN1")) {
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateCurrentFragment();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

**FINALLY**

My goal is I want to bind service with all activity. Also, service and activity should be able to talk with each other.. Is it possible ?? Please advice me some approach thx.

**NOTE**

I TRY to summarize my question but I don't know where to start.

I TRY to show some work around and want to tell what happen.

Sorry to make it a bit long long question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `Service` isn't the one that binds to activities, your `Service` is the component that is doing some operation and your activities are the ones that bind  to the service in order to get data from it or something.

So you need to bind to your service every time you open a new activity, your approach of having a base activity that binds to the service in its onCreate is pretty good.

and then you can have interfaces that your service implement so you can communicate with your service, and have some callbacks so your activity is notified when your service need to communicate back to activity.